# PostgreSQL connection URL using password file

Tags: postgresql

I am connecting to postgresql db on localhost using a url like this

`postgres://user:secret@/mydb?sslmode=disable`

Is it possible to use a `.pgpass` file in the above url so I don't have to expose my user/pw ?

Comment: Just leave them out: `postgres://@/mydb?sslmode=disable` should work

Comment: sorry for the delay.. your command almost worked... the full correct command is postgres:///mydb?sslmode=disable

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. basically ` postgres:///mydb?sslmode=disable` is able to conenct without check any auth and `postgres://@/mydb?sslmode=disable` gives error `"postgres://*:*@/?" error="failed to connect to `host=/tmp user= database=`: server error (FATAL: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet (SQLSTATE 28000))`